# How to convert and Immutablemultidict back to a string

Tags: python, immutability

I have an immutableMultiDict:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('redirect', u'true'), ('http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00KHWSB5M?gwSec', u'1'), ('ref_',
 u's9_simh_gw_p74_d15_i2')])
```

It was a string of a url: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00KHWSB5M?gwSec=1&redirect=true&ref_=s9_simh_gw_p74_d15_i2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00KHWSB5M)

But, as it was passed through APIs, Flask or JS changed it. Using python, how can I convert it back to a string?

If possible I would prefer a solution that works for all URLs. If this is not possible, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily convert the dictionary back to a string capturing the POST with `args`

Start your Flask app and in the browser add a key name to reference your params:

http://127.0.0.1:5000/test?convertthis=item1+item2

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def someMethod():
   # accept string arguments
   args = request.args
   print(args)
   # convert ImmutableMultiDict back to string
   values = args["convertthis"]
   print values

   return "Here is what was submitted:  " + "( " + values + " )"
```